# Make generated QR code downloadable on react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, qr-code

What I'm trying to do is to generate a **QR code** based on the Device Id to later download it. I figured out how to generate it, it shows OK on the page, everything is ok but is there any possible way to download it? (the QR image, it's a .png)

```
import QRCode from 'qrcode.react';
render() {
return (
<QRCode value={this.state.values.deviceId} />
)};
```

This is what I've done:

[image: Image 1]

This is what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: That library generates QR codes on a canvas, so searching for questions about exporting the canvas as an image might be helpful - I would recommend chaining the libraries 'canvas-to-blob' & 'file-saver' on npm together

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, here is the code:

```
import QRCode from 'qrcode.react';
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.download = this.download.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount(){
 this.download()
}
render() {
return (
 <div style={{display: "none"}} className="HpQrcode"> // hidden div
   <QRCode
     value={this.state.values._id}
     size={128}
     level={'H'}
   />
 </div>
  <a ref={(ref: any): any => this.downloadRef = ref}>
    Download QR Code
  </a>
)};
download() {
    const canvas: any = document.querySelector('.HpQrcode > canvas');
    this.downloadRef.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    this.downloadRef.download = this.state.values.deviceId + "-QR.png";
}
```